# Need ceiling fan remote that also uses controls at existing wall switch

Tags: ceiling-fan

I'm looking for a ceiling fan remote that will allow me to continue to use the wall switches. I am certain that the current wall switches will need to be replaced with the remote kit switches.  My current configuration is a toggle switch for the light and an off-low-med-hi-off rotary switch for the fan speed.  In other words, I have two hot wires going from the switch to the fan and do not ever use the pull-string switches on the fan.  To further complicate the situation, the light switch is a 3-way switch.

My story is (and I'm sticking to it) that I may be warm when I go to bed and would like to begin the night with the fan on and turn it off when I've cooled down.  Therefore I would keep the remote on the headboard to turn the fan off, but need to be able to turn the fan/light on/off at the door.

Answer (score 2):

I beleive that you can do this using a remote control switch set such as this [one](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-100654978/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&keyword=remote%20control%20switch&storeId=10051)

[image: remote]

You will need two switches, one for the light and one for the fan. The remote shown has two channels. You need to check that the fan does not exceed the wattage recommended and that the dimming circuit in the switch can handle a motor, not just incandescent lights.

Several manufacturers make these types of devices, so search for ones that meet these criteria. Here is [another version](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-202326055/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&keyword=lutron%20wireless&storeId=10051)

[image: remote2]

Comment: The store's description talks only of light control, not fan.

Comment: You need to dig a little further. Check the manufacturers' websites to see if they have other version that fit the specifics you need. Then search the internet to find a supplier.